# Nested for loop ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, for-loop

I have multiple GDBs from an earlier process. Each GDB contains a single feature class (FC).

I want to copy (FeatureClassToFeatureClass) each FC into a "Main" GDB for later processing in a single place.

I thought nesting a for loop like below would work. It runs, but doesn't produce a result or an error, so it's unclear why it's not working.

*I am using Python 2.7.14 in a Windows Server environment, running with ArcGIS Desktop Advanced (10.6).*

```py
#Import modules
import arcpy
import os

#Target GDB
outGDB = r"E:\Jamie_Temp\Main_GDB.gdb"

#LIBRARIES
#Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:\Jamie_Temp\Test_Files"

#Find GDBs
inGDB = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()

for gdb in inGDB:
    inFCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in inFCs:
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, outGDB, fc.strip("_point"))
```

The idea being here that it:

1. Finds the name of all GDBs in the workspace and assigns them to `inGDB`
2. Loops through each GDB found in `inGDB` and list the FCs inside, assigning them to `inFCs`
3. Copy the FCs found to `Main_GDB.gdb`

Comment: As a general advice I would add a r before each path, e.g. r"E:\Jamie_Temp\Main_GDB.gdb" and I would not use spaces in paths, so change Test Files to TestFiles or Test_Files. This will probably not fix the issue, but it is worth a try at least!

Comment: Edited and tested, no difference I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to find any `inFCs` as you're not setting `arcpy.env.workspace` to a `gdb` before calling `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` which looks in the *current* workspace.

Try (untested):

```
#Import modules
import arcpy
import os

#Target GDB
outGDB = r"E:\Jamie_Temp\Main_GDB.gdb"

#LIBRARIES
#Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = ws = r"E:\Jamie_Temp\Test_Files" # note setting "ws" var here

#Find GDBs
inGDB = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()

for gdb in inGDB:
    arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(ws, gdb)
    # Or if gdb is a full path
    # arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
    

    inFCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in inFCs:
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, outGDB, fc.strip("_point"))
```

Comment: Spot on, does exactly what I need, thanks!